# Combine columns in pandas to create a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, feature-engineering

Hello I am working on pandas dataframe and I want to create a column combining multiple columns and applying condition on them and I am looking for a smart way to do it.

Suppose the data frame looks as

```
A   B   C   D
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   1   0
1   0   1   0
1   1   1   0
0   0   1   1
```

My output column should be as below

```
A   B   C   D   Output_col
1   0   0   0   A
0   1   0   0   B
0   0   1   0   C
1   0   1   0   A_C
1   1   1   0   A_B_C
0   0   1   1   C_D
```

I can certainly achieve this using below code but then I have to do it for every column.

```
test['Output_col'] = test.A.apply(lambda x: A if x > 0 else 0)
```

I was wondering if there is a way where I could achieve this without applying to every column if I have very large number of columns.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + `join`.
Select column names using `x.index`(
**note that `axis = 1` is used**) + [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to filter the selected columns :

```
test['Output_col']=test.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.index[x.eq(1)]),axis=1)
print(test)
```

---

```
   A  B  C  D Output_col
0  1  0  0  0          A
1  0  1  0  0          B
2  0  0  1  0          C
3  1  0  1  0        A_C
4  1  1  1  0      A_B_C
5  0  0  1  1        C_D
```

---

To apply only a list of columns:

```
my_list_columns=['enter element of your list']
test['Output_col']=test[my_list_columns].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.index[x.eq(1)]),axis=1)
print(test)
```

---

case to all columns is 0

```
my_list_columns=['A','B','C','D']
df['Output_col']=df[my_list_columns].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.index[x.eq(1)])  if x.eq(1).any() else 'no_value',axis=1)
print(df)

   A  B  C  D Output_col
0  1  0  0  0          A
1  0  0  0  0   no_value
2  0  0  1  0          C
3  1  0  1  0        A_C
4  1  0  1  0        A_C
5  0  0  1  1        C_D
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for response, but I need to apply this on a list of columns only but this I believe would be applied on all the columns in a data frame. Any way I can apply this only a list of columns. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: thanks this is exactly I was looking for and it does the magic, however for all the rows where it was zero for all columns it seems it generated white space cells which I tried to fix using `test['Output_col'] = test['Output_col'].str.replace(" ", 'no_value')`. But this doesnt seem to be helping. Any way to fix this as well

Comment: Why do you think there are blank spaces? if `test ['out_col'] = test['out_col'] str.replace ("  "," no_value ")` does not work, it is because there are no blank spaces. It may be because of the way the data is justified

Comment: I am glad to help you!

Comment: I understand, then how do I fix it, How do I make sure that `output_col` to have a value of `no_vaue` when all the columns have zero

Comment: Use: `df['Output_col']=df[my_list_columns].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.index[x.eq(1)])  if x.eq(1).any() else 'no_value',axis=1)`

Comment: Yeah, did the same. Thanks a lot for your help today. now works exactly the way I was looking for, has helped me reduce a lot of manual task.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: for a subset of columns (I use method 2)

```
cols = ['A', 'B']
df1 = df[cols]
s = df1.columns + '-'
df['Output_col'] = df1.dot(s).str[:-1]

Out[54]:
   A  B  C  D Output_col
0  1  0  0  0          A
1  0  1  0  0          B
2  0  0  1  0
3  1  0  1  0          A
4  1  1  1  0        A-B
5  0  0  1  1
```

---

Try this combination of `str.replace` and `dot`

```
df['Output_col'] = df.dot(df.columns).str.replace(r'(?<!^)(?!$)','-')

Out[32]:
   A  B  C  D Output_col
0  1  0  0  0          A
1  0  1  0  0          B
2  0  0  1  0          C
3  1  0  1  0        A-C
4  1  1  1  0      A-B-C
5  0  0  1  1        C-D
```

---

If you feel uneasy with regex pattern. You may try this way without using `str.replace`

```
s = df.columns + '-'
df['Output_col'] = df.dot(s).str[:-1]

Out[50]:
   A  B  C  D Output_col
0  1  0  0  0          A
1  0  1  0  0          B
2  0  0  1  0          C
3  1  0  1  0        A-C
4  1  1  1  0      A-B-C
5  0  0  1  1        C-D
```

Comment: Hey Andy., thanks for your response, but not working for list of columns, again this would be applied to entire data set

Comment: @AnalyticsTeam: oh, in that case just  slice on list of columns you want and work on that sliced dataframe and assign back to `df`. I edited answer to show it

Answer (score 0):

This builds off a solution provided by @Jezrael : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61570096/7175713)

```
df['Output_col'] = df.dot(df.columns.str.cat(['_']*len(df.columns),sep='')).str.strip('_')



    A   B   C   D   Output_col
0   1   0   0   0   A
1   0   1   0   0   B
2   0   0   1   0   C
3   1   0   1   0   A_C
4   1   1   1   0   A_B_C
5   0   0   1   1   C_D
```