# Creating a label column based on vectorized labels

Tags: python, pandas

**I have data in the form of**

```
    image_id    healthy     multiple_diseases   rust    scab
0   Train_0     0           0                   0       1
1   Train_1     0           1                   0       0
2   Train_2     1           0                   0       0
```

**And I would like to add a label column, where the label would be where 1 is in each row, so:**

```
    image_id    healthy     multiple_diseases   rust    scab    label
0   Train_0     0           0                   0       1       scab
1   Train_1     0           1                   0       0       multiple_diseases
2   Train_2     1           0                   0       0       healthy
```

**Currently, my solution is this:**

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (df.at[index, 'healthy'] == 1):
        df.at[index,'label'] = 'healthy'
    elif (df.at[index, 'multiple_diseases'] == 1):
        df.at[index,'label'] = 'multiple_diseases'
    elif (df.at[index, 'rust'] == 1):
        df.at[index,'label'] = 'rust'
    elif (df.at[index, 'scab'] == 1):
        df.at[index,'label'] = 'scab'
```

But this approach is quite ugly and gets worse the more labels there are.

***What would be a better way to do this?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is always only one `1` per row use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) by all columns without first:

```
df['label'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.columns[1:])
print (df)
  image_id  healthy  multiple_diseases  rust  scab              label
0  Train_0        0                  0     0     1               scab
1  Train_1        0                  1     0     0  multiple_diseases
2  Train_2        1                  0     0     0            healthy
```

If possible multiple `1` per row add separator:

```
print (df)
  image_id  healthy  multiple_diseases  rust  scab
0  Train_0        0                  0     0     1
1  Train_1        0                  1     0     0
2  Train_2        1                  0     0     1

df['label'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.columns[1:] + ',').str.rstrip(',')
print (df)
  image_id  healthy  multiple_diseases  rust  scab              label
0  Train_0        0                  0     0     1               scab
1  Train_1        0                  1     0     0  multiple_diseases
2  Train_2        1                  0     0     1       healthy,scab
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a play on ur question - @jezrael's solution is succinct.

[numpy extract](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.extract.html#numpy.extract) and [numpy broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) to are used here to get the labels per row - Note that this works if there is just one True per row :

```
#get the columns that contain just the numbers
cols = df.columns[1:]
#get only the numbers
relevant = df.to_numpy()[:,1:]

#extract the relevant column if it has a 1(True) associated with it
df['labels'] = np.extract(relevant,np.broadcast_to(cols,relevant.shape))

print(df)


    image_id    healthy multiple_diseases   rust    scab    labels
0   Train_0         0      0                 0       1       scab
1   Train_1         0      1                 0       0       multiple_diseases
2   Train_2         1      0                 0       0       healthy
```

You could also achieve the same thing with [itertools' compress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) function :

```
from itertools import compress
cols = df.columns[1:]
relevant = df.to_numpy()[:,1:]
res = [','.join(compress(cols,entry)).strip(',') for entry in relevant]
df['label'] = res
print(res)
['scab', 'multiple_diseases', 'healthy']
```

if applied to the other example @jezrael provided, you should get the same results :

Again, just a play, on the different options, and limitations ... the conciseness of @jezrael's solution makes it super.